# sms.sendTextMessage sends messages but force closes

Tags: android

Edit: the solution was to put Main.this in place of null in my toast.

i am using AsyncTask to send text messages and they all get sent successfully (i have tested sending 50 to myself) but the application instantly force closes when i press send. i used breakpoints and i decided that the application force closes after the "sms.sendTextMessage..." loop. Here is my main.java.

```
package com.dillonregi.spamsms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void sms(View view) {
Toast.makeText(this, "sms()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long>() {
protected Long doInBackground(String... params){
     EditText number = (EditText) Main.this.findViewById(R.id.pnumber);
     EditText message = (EditText) Main.this.findViewById(R.id.pmessage);
     EditText hmany = (EditText) Main.this.findViewById(R.id.hmany);
     String _hmany = hmany.getText().toString();
     final String _number = number.getText().toString();
     final String _message = message.getText().toString();
     final int xtime = Integer.parseInt(_hmany);

     mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
     Toast.makeText(null, "number: " + _number + " message: " + _message + " xtime: " + xtime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
     });

     long sentTexts = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < xtime; i++) {       
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(_number, null, _message, null, null);
        //send SMS's
        sentTexts += 1;
    }
    return sentTexts;
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

}

protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
           Toast.makeText(null, "number of texts sent will end up going here. maybe add + sentTexts after these quotes?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}.execute(); }
}
```

And the LogCat

> 07-15 16:09:39.152: W/dalvikvm(29508): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40019560)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:89)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at com.dillonregi.spamsms.Main$1$1.run(Main.java:37)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
>   07-15 16:09:39.152: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:89)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at com.dillonregi.spamsms.Main$1$1.run(Main.java:37)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
>   07-15 16:09:39.162: E/AndroidRuntime(29508):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: see my answer, You are a new user on  Stackoverflow try to upvote or accept correct answers, to help other to get the right answer if they face same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it make sense??

```
Toast.makeText(null, "number: " + _number + " message: " + _message + " xtime: " + xtime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

you are passing `null` instead of `Context` change it with

```
Toast.makeText(Main.this , "number: " + _number + " message: " + _message + " xtime: " + xtime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: for more read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: you have also change this line also `Toast.makeText(null, "number of texts sent will end up going here. maybe add + sentTexts after these quotes?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` ? null with Main.this ??

Answer (score 1):

your Logcat show this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29508): java.lang.NullPointerException 07-15 16:09:39.152:
```

`E/AndroidRuntime(29508): at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:89) 07-15 16:09:39.152:` `E/AndroidRuntime(29508): at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231) 07-15 16:09:39.152:`

So your error is basically you passed a null pointer to your Toast widget and compiler complain about this!!

in `onPostExecute()` method replace your toast with this one:

make `sentTexts` as attribute of you class

```
Toast.makeText(Main.this, "number of texts sent will end up going here. maybe add" + sentTexts + "after these quotes?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I ended up using 
Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Sent " + sentTexts, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
how would i go about making it a global variable? (i tried public/private/global long sentTexts)

Comment: making what a global variable?

Comment: @Ran I would like to say make it as attribute in the class

Comment: @Ran a variable, in this case it was sentTexts.
i ended up making it into numTexts (for number of text messages sent) because sentTexts is not a string (it's "long") and it was causes issues. so now numTexts = sentTexts, but numTexts isn't global so therefore it cannot be resolved to a variable in onPostExecute.

Comment: @K_Anas can you give me a link explaining what a class attribute is, and how i would incorporate that into my script?
thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException at the line `Toat.makeToast` where you send `null` as the first parameter, where the context should be.

All the signs point to the same place...